# Layout problem with Custom List and native controls

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to have a layout with 6 TextViews and a Custom List.
TextView number 3,4,5 have images next to them,followed by the Custom List.

The custom list is done , but I am not sure how I can get the upper part ( TextView controls and images ) and the custom list in one layout. 
For other custom lists I have always extended from ListActivity and set the list adapter in the same class as it is the only control on the screen. 
In this case the class extends from Activity,how can I set the list adapter in the Activity class ?

Any pointer's to achieve this layout and which layout will be the optimal choice(Linear,Relative..)  ?

Thanks,
Salil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem.

1. Add a `listview` to the layout xml
2. Get the `listview` object using `findViewById`
3. User `etAdapter` to set the custom list adapter

Now I can use the custom list along with other controls in the same Activity.

Thanks,
Salil.